# React native firebase - facebook sign-in not triggering onAuthStateChanged listener

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

this is the second problem Im having with RNFB facebook login.

Im following the [official code sample](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth) provided by RNFB....code below

Problem is with the line `firebase().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);`....its not triggering the firebase listener `auth().onAuthStateChanged`
All other code is running as it should and `facebookCredential` variable is populated correctly

```
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

  onFacebookButtonPress = async () => {
    // Attempt login with permissions
    const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
      'public_profile',
      'email',
    ]);

    if (result.isCancelled) {
      throw 'User cancelled the login process';
    }

    // Once signed in, get the users AccesToken
    const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    if (!data) {
      throw 'Something went wrong obtaining access token';
    }

    // Create a Firebase credential with the AccessToken
    //const facebookCredential = firebase.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);
    const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
      data.accessToken,
    );

    // Sign-in the user with the credential
    firebase().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
  };
```

Comment: have you checked your import? ```import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';``` and replace any ```firebase.auth()``` with only ```auth``` ?

Comment: I amended code and still getting the same issue.....its looks like the signInWithCredential method is not recognized

Comment: did u tried seeing the value of "facebookCredential"?

Comment: can you show your onAuthStateChanged?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by putting a try/catch around the problematic line.  Turned out was because I had already once signed in using Google.

```
An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't wait till something goes wrong before you add try/ catch's. `signInWithCredential` returns many different types of [errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithcredential), which you handle. From the docs:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  if (errorCode === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
    alert('Email already associated with another account.');
    // Handle account linking here, if using.
  } else {
    console.error(error);
  }
 });
```

Please handle the other error cases too :

> auth/account-exists-with-different-credential
>
> auth/invalid-credential
>
> auth/operation-not-allowed
>
> auth/user-disabled

**and more.**